# Create responsive image tag with only low res content

Tags: image, resolution, image-resizing, responsive-images

How can we construct a responsive image tag to insure that the browser chooses the image with the lowest *file size* that will fill its container, rather than choosing a higher resolution version?

I'm building a website with many images per page. We are more concerned about fast page load than we are with image quality. On a phone with a high resolution screen, we would rather the browser use the low resolution image than selecting a 2x image, for example, even if there is a bit of pixelation evident.

How would we construct an img tag or picture tag to accomplish this?

I've tried this:

```
<img
src="//placehold.it/992x662"
srcset="//placehold.it/1024x683 1024w,
    //placehold.it/992x662 992w,
    //placehold.it/768x512 768w,
    //placehold.it/544x363 544w"
sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 1024px,
    (min-width: 992px) 992px,
    (min-width: 768px) 768px,
    (min-width: 544px) 544px,
    calc(100vw - 30px)"
/>
```

but Retina phones choose the largest file where we want them to use the smallest one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `<picture>` for this:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="//placehold.it/1024x683">
  <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="//placehold.it/992x662">
  <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="//placehold.it/768x512">
  <source media="(min-width: 544px)" srcset="//placehold.it/544x363">
  <img src="//placehold.it/992x662" />
</picture>
```